# JAX-RS web service using jquery facing error 404

Tags: java, jquery, web-services

This is my `web.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>NewsPortal</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
         <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.newsportal</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>       
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**There may be something wrong with `web.xml` but I am not sure.**

**Here is my web service .**

```
package com.newsportal;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

import com.newsportal.utility.ErrorReporting;

@Path("/Authentication")
public class AuthenticationResource {

    @POST   
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/login")
    public Response  login(@FormParam("emailOrPhone") String emailOrPhone,@FormParam("password") String password){
        String response ="";
        try{

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ErrorReporting.webServiceError(ex);
        }
        return Response.ok(response)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .build();
    }
}
```

**This is JAX-RS i think here most of the code looks fine .**
**Here is my jquery I am trying to invoke this login method**

```
var Index = function() {

    var handleIndexLoad = function() {
        // no authentication at load
    }
    var handlelogin = function() {
        var emailOrPhone='admin@nextolive.com';
        var password    ='12345';
        $.ajax({
            method : "POST",
            url : "Authentication/login/",
            data :'emailOrPhone='+ emailOrPhone +'&password='+password,         
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

    }
    return {
        // main function to initiate the module
        init : function() {
            handleIndexLoad();
            handlelogin();
        }

    };

}();
```

This is `index.js` file . I think here also things are fine .

To be honest I am new to Java so , i am not really sure if I am following 
the right pattern .
Please tell me what i need to  do fix it .

Comment: Expecting that you have deployed the webservice correctly. Other thing which is wrong here is that, you are sending the data `emailOrPhone` and `password` as `payload` and expecting it to be `FormData` in the webservice.

Comment: i changed it to  var emailOrPhone='admin@nextolive.com';
        var password    ='12345';
        var data =  new FormData();
        data.append('emailOrPhone',emailOrPhone);
        data.append('password',password);
  $.ajax({
   method : "POST",
   url : "Authentication/login/",
   data :data, 
   processData: false,
   contentType: false
  }).done(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
  });

Comment: but still 404 error

Comment: since you have mentioned `/rest` in `servlet-mapping -> url-pattern` change the URL to `/rest/Authentication/login`